How can I distribute the legs to equalize the hypotenuses?
I'm not even sure I'm asking this correctly.
I have a series of triangles. $p^2 + q^2 = s^2$
I have a collection of $[p_1, p_2, ... p_n]$ and a total of $q_{tot}$ that needs to be distributed so that the magnitude of the hypotenuse is always the same $s_1 = s_2 = ... = s_n$.
$$ s_1 = \sqrt{p_1^2 + q_1^2}$$
$$ s_2 = \sqrt{p_2^2 + q_2^2}$$
$$ ... $$
$$ s_n = \sqrt{p_n^2 + q_n^2}$$
It has been a long time since I've used anything above trigonometry, and some basic calculus. I don't remember the linear-algebra/differential equations that is probably useful to solve this, but it could be much more simple.
If I can solve for $s$ then I can calculate each of the $q$ values individually.
Solving if there were only two sets:
$$ \sqrt{p_1^2 + q_1^2} = \sqrt{p_2^2 + q_2^2} $$
Square both sides
$$ p_1^2 + q_1^2 = p_2^2 + q_2^2 $$
The $p$s are known constants
$$ c + q_1^2 = c + q_2^2 $$
$$ q_1^2 = c + q_2^2 $$
$$ q_1^2 - q_2^2 = c $$
Since $q_{tot} = q_1 + q_2$
$$ q_1^2 - (q_{tot} - q_1)^2 = c $$
Since $q_{tot}$ and $c$ are known constants, I can solve for $q_1$. Then solve for $s_1$ which equals $s_2$ ergo I can find $q_2$.
But how do I do this with $n$ sets?
I honestly don't even remember the correct terminology to search for the answer.

Interesting question. It will be easier to make the squares of all the hypotenuses equal. It's not clear to me how much easier.

Are these variables real numbers or integers? What is the required relationship between $q_{tot}$ and the other quantities?

@GregMartin these variables are real numbers (can be decimal). The only relationship is $q_{tot} = \Sigma_1^n q_n \pm \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is an accepted variability to account for rounding.

For simplicity suppose that $p_1 \le \cdots \le p_n$.
Note that we have $q_j = \sqrt{s^2-p_j^2}$ for all $1\le k\le n$; here the $p_j$ are known quantities and $s\ge p_n$ is a parameter. The function $\sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{s^2 - p_j^2}$ is an increasing function of $s$, and so as long as $q_{tot}$ is at least as large as its minimum possible value $\sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{p_n^2 - p_j^2}$, there will be a unique value of $s$ for which $\sum_{j=1}^n q_j = q_{tot}$.
Algebraically finding this value of $s$ seems very difficult (when $n\ge3$), but one can certainly use root-finding algorithms such as Newton's method to solve $\sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{s^2 - p_j^2} = q_{tot}$ for $s$ to any desired precision.

We can suppose that $p_1 \le ... \le p_n$ as the order does not matter. Also, we can assume that $q_tot$ will always be a value where the desired equalized distribution is possible. So, we are trying to find $s$ as that would allow us to plug it into any set.
Thank you for this information. I feel like with this, I can at least try to start figuring it out.
